# How to Make `Var` Instance of `Free` Data Type?

Tags: haskell

While reading [Typeclassopedia](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Monad)'s chapter on Monads, I saw:

```
data Free f a = Var a
               | Node (f (Free f a))
```

I typed `:i Free` to get information on it.

```
ghci> :i Free
type role Free nominal nominal
data Free (f :: * -> *) a = Var a | Node (f (Free f a))
```

I've seen types with `kind`'s of `* -> *`:

```
ghci> :k []
[] :: * -> *
ghci> :k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
```

But, I'm not sure how to make a simple `Var` instance with an argument of `* -> *`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you create a Var is just `Var value`, like `Var "x"` for example. Since `f` does not actually appear in the definition of `Var`, your choice of `f` does not actually affect how you create a Var - it only matters when creating Nodes.

So when creating a Node with `f` being `[]`, you'd write `Node [Var "x"]` and for `Maybe` you'd write `Node (Some (Var "x"))`. As you see the use of `Var` stays the same in both cases, you just pass a different "collection" to the `Node` constructor.